# C++ 20 infinite backgroung job with timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I want to create an infinite background timer that should periodically output the size of the queue. I tried to use `std::async`, but is it possible not to use `sleep_for` an infinite loop?

Is there a way to pass this `secondsTimeout` interval directly to `std::async` or something else? I want my worker function to output only the size of the queue without additional logic. I use C++ 20.

```
void backgroundTimer(int secondsTimeout)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(secondsTimeout));
        std::cout << "Queue size: " << queueSize << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::async(timer, 1);

    ....
}
```

Comment: You could use a `std::thread` or you could implement an event loop (like in the Qt framework (and others)) and use a periodic timer to call a callback function (slot). There are other ways as well.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've heard about even loop, but I just wonder - if there is an out-of-the-box approach in the C++20? Like I create an async job, detach and it gets performed by the given period.

Comment: There's no real out-of-the-box solution for that (AFAIK). But all the building blocks you need to build one are there. There are also tons of external libraries available that can provide that functionality.

Comment: You certainly want to use a loop and a variation of `sleep_for()` (or `sleep_until()`), but you need to take account the time necessary to run your periodic task. Otherwise, with more calls, the period will be more and more unsynchronized with the original intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is can you do this without `sleep_for`. Of course you can. Here's what I do.

I already have a class that implements a work queue. There are various push methods for pushing work into the queue. And there's a `waitForWork()` method that takes an optional maximum time to wait.

The class also implements a `working` flag, so the code is simple:

```
while (workQueue.working()) {
    auto request = workQueue.waitForWork(20s);
    if (request != nullptr) {
        ... do the work
    }
    else if (workQueue.working()) {
        ... do your wake-up action
    }
}
```

Under the hood, there's a `std::mutex` and `std::cond_var`. `waitForWork()` returns nullptr if someone sets `working` to false.

I use this class for a proper work queue or any time I just want to have a worker thread wake up periodically -- because I get all the features I need for free. I'm not doing a while-true block, but instead have a proper variable with proper mutex locking and wakeup code, all collected in a nice fashion.

It's nice being able to shut down my worker threads correctly. I just call `workQueue.shutdown()`.